Return files without timeout in ASP.NET Core 8.0 MVC
I have a .NET route that I want to hit when I want to get a document, now It can either return Json or a full fledged file whose name and extension is determined through some logic.
Here some sample code:
public async Task<IActionResult> DownloadAndServeFile(List<string> num_lst, bool view)
{
    cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
    HttpContext.RequestAborted.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

    if (browserSupportedExtensions.Contains(Path.GetExtension(fileName).ToLower()) && view == "true")
    {
        string fileUrlToServe = Url.Content($"~/DownloadedFiles/{fileName}");
        return Json(new { success = true, url = fileUrlToServe, openInBrowser = true });
    }
    else
    {
        byte[] fileBytes = await System.IO.File.ReadAllBytesAsync(savePath);

        // adding bytes to memory stream
        return File(fileBytes, "application/octet-stream", fileName);
    }
}


And here's how I hit this endpoint from Javascript:

```js
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: '/Home/DownloadAndServeFile',
    data: { id: some_num },
    success: function (response, status, xhr) {
        // Check if the content type is JSON
        var contentType = xhr.getResponseHeader('Content-Type');

        if (contentType.includes('application/json')) {
            // The server returned a JSON response
            if (response.success) {
                window.location.href = response.url; 
                const link = document.createElement('a');
                link.href = response.url;
                link.download = '';  
                document.body.appendChild(link);
                link.click();
                document.body.removeChild(link); 
            }
            else {
                showToast(response.message, "error");
            }
        } else {
            // The server returned a file directly (binary data)
            console.log(xhr.getResponseHeader('Content-Disposition'));
            var fileName = xhr.getResponseHeader('Content-Disposition').split(';')[1].split('filename=')[1];
            var blob = new Blob([response], { type: xhr.getResponseHeader('Content-Type') });
            var link = document.createElement('a');
            link.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
            link.download = fileName;
            link.click();
           }
    },
    error: function (xhr, status, error) {
     }
});

The problem is: everything works as I want, but now suppose when the popup comes up the user presses no, instead of yes to download then the .NET connection times out.
My guess is that the server has started transmitting the file, but cannot get the user to acknowledge and it times itself out.
How do I fix this?

Hi, @Aggerio6969. I test your code in the new mvc application, and I didn't add this line "cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();" Then, I try to click the button to download the file, it goes to "return File(...)", but when I pressed no, this download was canceled directly. So, I want to know that if you encounter this issue when return File(), and which situation do you expect?

@YumiaoKong What I am getting on my side with and without the line is that if I press no on the download popup I get the error that IIS server exited with code 'The program '[21408] iisexpress.exe' has exited with code 4294967295 (0xffffffff).' .
I looked it up and found that it could be related to the connection timeout. Is there a way to fix this ?

Could you kindly provide the detailed error message? And you can try running this application using Kestrel by switching IIS Express to https in visual studio.
